# Regular Expression for specific string format <><><>

Tags: regex

Need regular expression to test following case:

Pattern: `<><><>`

Correct Example: `<abc><xyz><123>`

Possible Mistake: `<abc<xyz>><123`

I would like to check if all tokens `abc`, `xyz` etc are inside `<>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it:

```
^(?:<[^<>]*>)*$
```

In PHP you have to put a delimiter around the regexp:

```
preg_match('/^(?:<[^<>]*>)*$/', $string)
```

Comment: preg_match() [function.preg-match]: Unknown modifier '<'

Comment: You forgot the deimiter around the regexp.